# Lost control of log4j levels

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We recently upgraded from log4j 1.* to 2.17.1 in response to the vulnerability.  After making what I thought were the requisite changes to our pom.xml, etc, I found I seem to have no control over debugging levels - i.e., it seems to be stuck displaying everything from info on up, but not debug - not matter what level changes I make to my log4j.xml.  Hopefully the info I include here will be enough to identify the issue(s).  Thanks in advance.

log4j.xml

```
    <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%-5p] [%c{1}] [%M:%L] - %m%n"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="edu.mydomain.directory">
        <level value="debug"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="warn"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <priority value="warn"/>
        <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Pom.xml

```
<dependency> 
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> 
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>2.17.1</version> 
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version> 
   </dependency>
```

Implementation:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
…
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

log.info(“this appears”);
log.debug(“this doesn’t appear”);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the issue we have to understand the `logging` hierarchy.

[image]

As we can see any `Log` level defined as `Warn` will not be able to see the `Error` or `Fatal` level logs but can see `Info` and above.

Now coming back to your configuration. I can see you have defined `log` `level` to your packages but missed the `appender-ref` to it. So here log is only printed by `<root>` logger which is set to level `warn`.

Sample logger

```
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="edu.mydomain.directory" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
```

It is always good to have the `root` logger defined to level `error`. `Additivity` is also very important, if not set then log would be printed multiple times for each level. 
Once an event reaches a logger with its `additivity` set to false the event will not be passed to any of its parent loggers, regardless of their additivity setting.

For more information, you can refer the link below:

1. [Hierarchy and Architecture](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html)
2. [Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks so much - however, I added the AppenderRef and additivity as you suggested, but I am still unable to see debug messages.

Comment: I see that your log file name is log4j.xml. It should be log4j2.xml.

Comment: Please refer this link for further clarifications. https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-xml-configuration-example/

Comment: The depedency you have in pom is log4j-to-slf4j which belongs to log4j2 . Please refer link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.1 . I hope it helps.